# Localizing an IHP application

Tags: localization, ihp

Some features of the Haskell web framework IHP produce strings that are sen by the user, e.g. the error messages from validators like [`nonEmpty`](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/api-docs/IHP-ValidationSupport-ValidateField.html#v:nonEmpty), and they are all in English.

How would I use IHP to produce a page with a non-English audience? Or, even more interesting, produce a webpage that adjusts its language to the preferences of the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now I18n is not yet supported directly in IHP. You'd need to manually deal with this for now. [Validation error messages can be overriden using `withCustomErrorMessage`](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/validation.html#customizing-error-messages).